# Runtime error during file operation in C

Tags: c, file

I am trying to run a C code for file opening and whenever I do that I get a debug assertion failed message.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    printf("program to demonstrate file operations");
    fp1 = fopen("try1.txt","r");
    if (feof(fp1))
    {
        printf("Yes");
    }
    else 
        printf("No");

    printf("%f",fp1);

    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Debug assertion failure might be caused by `fp1` being null.
This will happen if the file could not have been opened.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (feof(fp1))
```

to

```
if (fp1 && !feof(fp1))
```

That is check for the return value of `fopen()`. If unable to open the file it would return NULL.

Edit:

> 1. Check if the file is in the same directory as that of exe/binary.
> 2. Check whether you have the permission to access the file.

Comment: thanks for the response .. it is printing no.. can u help me out in knowing why is the file not opening.?

Comment: i am sorry but it is not working for both the solutions.. thanks again for the help.. appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of

```
 fp1 = fopen("try1.txt","r");
```

first. It is fare to check the return values of all standard functions( with proper return values) before proceeding to next step. In this case "fp1" should not be NULL. Please check the file location or check whether file is present in current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the file is opened correctly or not
check if( fp==NULL) using an if condition

if fp==NULL is true, file is not being opened correctly

Answer (score 0):

Before using `feof()` on `fp`.
Ensure that `fopen()` succeeded.

```
#include <string.h>   /* For strerror() */
#include <errno.h>    /* For errno  */
#include <stdlib.h>   /* For exit() */

fp = fopen ("FaultyFile.txt", "r");

/* Add Error-checking */             
if (NULL == fp)                          
{
    printf ("Error No : [%d]\n", errno);
    printf ("Error Msg: [%s]\n", strerror(errno));
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);          
}
```

From `man(3) fopen`:
Return Value: Upon successful `fopen()` return a `FILE` pointer.  Otherwise, `NULL` is returned and `errno`  is  set  to indicate the error.

Comment: It means that the file `try1.txt` doesn't exist. Ensure this file is in the same directory as that of executable.